# How do I expand a snippet, while inside of another snippet?

Tags: sublimetext, code-snippets, sublimetext3

In Sublime Text 3, I'm trying to insert a snippet inside of a snippet, aka

```
ul[TAB]
```

which produces

```
<ul>|</ul>
```

with the cursor nested between the elements.

Now, what I'd want to do is be able to expand another snippet inside of this snippet, aka

```
ul[TAB]li[TAB]
```

rendering

```
<ul><li>|</li></ul>
```

once again with the cursor nested between the elements, unfortunately as part of snippets in sublime text 3, [TAB] brings you to the next anchor point, in this case, exiting the tag. I find this feature incredibly handy, but in this case, a PITA. The above listed keystrokes would render:

```
<ul>li</ul>|
```

with the cursor after the closing tag.

Is there a way to exit out of the snippet, so that I can then enter a new snippet?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can specify the position of the cursor using `$0`, example:

```
<snippet>
<content><![CDATA[
<ul>$0</ul>
]]></content>
    <tabTrigger>ul</tabTrigger>
    <scope>text.html</scope>
</snippet>
```

I recommend taking a look at the excellent [Emmet](http://emmet.io/) plugin, as it makes scaffolding of nested HTML tags pretty easy.

Comment: @idleberg  This is great when there is a single `field` in the snippet; any ideas on how to make it work when there are multiple fields within the same snippet without creating a new key binding [as suggested in the answer to this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43563431/st3-swap-priority-of-tab-function-within-a-snippet-nested-snippets?noredirect=1&lq=1)?