# ST3 swap priority of tab function within a snippet (nested snippets)

Tags: tabs, sublimetext3, code-snippets

Find myself frequently invoking a snippet within a snippet, but of course when I go to expend the nested snippet, the tab key moves me to either the next entry of the first snippet or the end of the first snippet (at which point, I have to replace the cursor at the end of the tab-trigger expression for the 2nd snippet and hit tab, at which point the 2nd snippet is expanded).

eg. given snippet `[ content A ${1:First point in A} and ${2: Second point in A} ]` with tab-trigger `tabtrigA` and snippet `[ content B ]` with tab-trigger `tabtrigB`

I'd like to be able to do the following:

In[1]:

```
tabtrigA % Hit tab to expand snippet A
```

Out[1]:

```
 [ content **A First point in A** and ${2: Second point in A} ] % where everything between ** ** is highlighted
```

Now replace `**...**` content with `tabtrigB`

In[2]:

```
     [ content tabtrigB* and ${2: Second point in A} ] % where * marks location of cursor.
```

and hitting `tab` would result in:

Out[2]:

```
 [ content [ content B ]* and ${2: Second point in A} ] % where * marks location of cursor
```

and hitting `tab` again would then jump to second entry of snippet A

Obviously this is tiresome: **is it possible to switch the priority assignment of `tab` so that it first acts as a tab-trigger and only jumps to next entry if there is no tab-trigger?**

---

Update: as of April 2019, still no solution for triggering a snippet within a snippet.

Comment: have you tried setting `"auto_complete_with_fields": true,` in your user preferences file?

Comment: @KeithHall - yes, this doesn't seem to change the behavior: it still jumps to the next entry in the snippet (or to the end of the snippet) instead of triggering the 2nd snippet. Please let me know if you have any other ideas - been searching for a while on this one and it is really tiresome!

Answer (score 3):

I don't think sublime can tell *this* snippets' next_field from *that* snippet's next_field. You can only ask if it has_next_field, any. But you could go with workarounds:

---

### Trigger your nested snippet with something else than TAB:

1. Through `command palette` by giving your nested snippet a `description`. The snippet below will be callable from the palette as **Snippet: description_for_command_palette**.

```
<snippet>
<content><![CDATA[
[ content B ]
]]></content>
<description>description_for_command_palette</description>
</snippet>
```

2. Through keybinding to the snippet path:

`{ "keys": ["ctrl+0"], "command": "insert_snippet", "args": {"name": "Packages/User/your_snippet.sublime-snippet"}}`

3. Through a keybinding to an anonymous snippet:

`{ "keys": ["ctrl+0"], "command": "insert_snippet", "args": {"contents": "[ content B ]"}}`

---

### Overwrite the keybinding to go to the next field in snippet to, say, enter.

Just add two keybindings:

```
{ "keys": ["enter"], "command": "next_field", "context":
[
{ "key": "has_next_field", "operator": "equal", "operand": true }
]
},
{ "keys": ["tab"], "command": "insert_best_completion", "args": {"default": "\t", "exact": false}, "context":
[
{ "key": "has_next_field", "operator": "equal", "operand": true }
]
}
```

Comment: The answer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23236247/how-do-i-expand-a-snippet-while-inside-of-another-snippet?rq=1) provides another solution in the case that there is only one `field` in the snippet. In short, it obtains the desired result by specifying exit-placement of the cursor using `${0:}`. Of course this wouldn't work for the case described here.